# TranslateTransform Within a ControlTemplate for a Button

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm making a custom button in my application resources... and I want to make it so that when the user clicks on the button.. the text will do a TranslateTransform.. basically moving the text of the button to emulate the button being pressed.  None of the examples I can find online explain how I can do this though.

It's alot easier if it's just a simple property.. but the code-behind for the Translate Transform is rather complicated:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Test" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform Y="5" X="-5"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    </TextBlock>
```

Or else I could do a simple "Setter Property etc etc".  this is what i have so far for my button

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RCSButtonFace}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="WhiteSmoke" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource WrappingStyle}" />
                                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="rectangle" Value="1.5"/>                                
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <!--<Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="#D6FFD6"/>-->
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="LightGray"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: An easier way to do this is to have a margin, and just increase the margin.

Comment: lol ya that would be alot easier.. i can try that